# How to have this result with Linq Request?

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, properties

This is my list

int specifiedvalue=6.5;

Name   Value
A      6.5
A      6.0
B      6.5
B      6.0
C      7.75
D      7.0

I would like to remove from this list objects which have the same name and a different value than the specifiedvalue(6.5) and keep the rest.

The result should be like:
A      6.5
B      6.5
C      7.75
D      7.0

Thanks

Comment: Show your real code, and what you have tried, and if you have this working without linq, that too.

Comment: What is the type of the items in your list?

Comment: I still have no code. I'm just trying to figure out the solution on paper for now.

Comment: The type is a type I created I don't understand why it could be useful to know it ? Type name is Lens he has 2 porperties a name (string) and a value (int)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you wrote that, the type of the `specifiedValue` is `int`. But the vaue is floating point and you must change it as `double`.

I am supposing that, you have declared your class like that:

```
public class Lens
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public double Value { get; set; }

     public Lens(string name, double value)
     {
           Name = name;
           Value = value;
     }
}
```

Here I am initializing the objects:

```
double specidifedValue = 6.5;

List<Lens> pairs = new List<Lens>();
pairs.Add(new Lens("A", 6.5));
pairs.Add(new Lens("A", 6.0));
pairs.Add(new Lens("B", 6.5));
pairs.Add(new Lens("B", 6.0));
pairs.Add(new Lens("C", 7.75));
pairs.Add(new Lens("D", 7.0));
```

And with that, firstly I am finding `Name`s which are occured more than one time in the list. And then selecting those with the value 6.5.

```
var keysMoreThanOne = pairs.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
      .Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

List<Lens> filteredPairs = pairs
  .Where(x => (keysMoreThanOne.Contains(x.Name) && x.Value == specidifedValue) 
  || !keysMoreThanOne.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
```

The result is as you want.

---

**Update**:

```
var result = new List<Lens>();
var keysMoreThanOne = pairs.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

if (specidifedValue > 0)
{
    result = pairs.Where(x => (keysMoreThanOne.Contains(x.Name) && x.Value == specidifedValue) ||
            !keysMoreThanOne.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
}
else
{
    result = pairs.Where(x => (keysMoreThanOne.Contains(x.Name) && 
        x.Value == pairs.Where(y=> y.Name==x.Name).OrderByDescending(y=> y.Value).First().Value)
        || !keysMoreThanOne.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code is better for my case...but I have a special case: when the specifiedValue can't be found I would like to take the largest one...How can I do that with your code? I tried to replace x.Value == specidifedValue by something else but I couldn't find out...thanks

Comment: @PaulMartinez In my opinion, @Igor's answer more suitable for your special case, when the specifiedValue can't be found. I suggest you, to make two different functions. One woth mine, and the other with Igor's answer. Then check the `specifiedValue` inside the `If` statement and call one of the functions. Because, if we try to take both into the considiration in one statement, it could give us a bad performance.

Comment: With Igor's code the problem is I don't know how to paste all the properties of my object in the new object it creates. Because my object has a lot of properties in fact...

Comment: @PaulMartinez See my update, I am checking the specifiedValue's value inside the if statement. And according to the situation one of the methods is executed. You can change the if condition as you want.

Comment: Actually the edited code doesn't fit with my case.  Im' going to post the code I need in a new answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
internal class NameValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}

var sourceList = new List<NameValue>
{
    new  NameValue {Name = "A", Value = 6.5},
    new  NameValue {Name = "A", Value = 6.0},
    new  NameValue {Name = "B", Value = 6.5},
    new  NameValue {Name = "B", Value = 6.0},
    new  NameValue {Name = "C", Value = 7.75},
    new  NameValue {Name = "D", Value = 7.0}
};

var result = sourceList.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
   .Select(x => new
   {
     Name = x.Key,
     Value = x.Max(y => y.Value)
   });
```

Comment: @PaulMartinez But it will give false result if your list has: `A 6.5`,
`A 7.0`